# Add default, fall-back action for controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a controller with a single index action. The same resource has some static assets which don't require anything in the controller. There used to be some others which are now gone but there are lingering links here and there on the web.

Is there a way I can match any `/resource/*` request that doesn't have an action defined in the controller or a named view in `app/views/resources/____` and route it to a default (`resource#index` would be fine in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyConstraint
  BYPASSED_ROUTES = ['anything']

  def matches?(request)
    BYPASSED_ROUTES.map {|r| request.path.include?(r)}.empty?
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # Insert other routes before the catch-all one
  match "/resource/*path" => "resource#index", :constraints => MyConstraint.new
end
```